# Valid reencryption of simple mixnet

Tags: fiat-shamir, mixnets

How can I provide a non interactive proof using the Fiat Shamir method for the valid reencryption of a simple mixnet?

Comment: With "Fiat Shamir", did you mean a proof systems with quadratic residues and RSA modulus?  What kind of ciphertext is there with this mixnet? What would google return on a basic "mixnet re-encryption proof" query?  Welcome to stackexchange. Some homework is expected.